Как узнать находиться ли окно в tkinter в переднем плане windows?
Как проверить находиться ли окно tkinter на переднем плане?
У меня есть приложение на socket и хочу сделать так, чтобы если приходило сообщение и окно не было на переднем плане, то выходило уведомление о новом сообщении.
Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо.
